# How to create nuget package of .zip file

Tags: nuget-package

I have a .zip file which contains 3 directory(folder) inside this.
Now I want to create a nuget package for this .zip file so that I can use this into my git repo.
I know basic way to create nuget package though not sure how to create for existing .zip file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

> No matter what your package does or what code it contains, you use one
> of the CLI tools, either nuget.exe or dotnet.exe, to package that
> functionality into a component that can be shared with and used by any
> number of other developers. To install NuGet CLI tools, see Install
> NuGet client tools.